# Specifying default value from lambda in a migration

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I want to add a non-null column `unique_id` to some of my models. The implementation for this would basically be `SecureRandom.hex(8)`. Is there a way to specify this in the migration itself, such that it computes the default values for all the **older** rows.

Maybe something like this:

`add_column :users, :unique_id, :string, null: false, default: proc { generate_unique_id }.call`

The problem is, the above method will generate `unique_id` only once (which is kind of expected). Is there a way to specify for generating default for every row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible directly in `add_column`. The common approach would be:

- create a nullable column;
- fill it with generated uids;
- update the column definition.

In your code, `proc { generate_unique_id }.call` makes not much sense, since it is an absolute equavalent of `generate_unique_id`.

```
 add_column :users, :unique_id, :string, null: true
 # it’s still a plain ruby code!
 User.find_each do |u|
   # or better use built-in SQL functoin to do this in batch
   #    inside your db, instead of performing a dozillion of updates
   u.update_column(:unique_id, generate_unique_id)
 end
 change_column :users, :unique_id, :string, null: false # NOW!
```

Comment: hmm.. ok. Makes sense.